# Errors in if statements in R Shiny checkBoxGroupInput

Tags: r, if-statement, checkbox, shiny

I am getting errors in my if statements with checkBoxGroupInput in my R Shiny App. Please ignore the fact that all the plots I want to output are the same - I will change this later.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

plotdata <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
colnames(plotdata) <- c("Year1", "RLIMona", "Year2", "RLICatalina", "Year3", "RLILaParguera1998", "Year4", "RLILAPARGUERA2004")
parguera <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
parguera <- select(parguera, 5:8)
colnames(parguera) <- c("Year", "1998 Expedition", "Year", "2004 Expedition")
monaisland <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
monaisland <- select(monaisland, 1:2)
colnames(monaisland) <- c("Year", "Mona Island RLI")
islacatalina <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
islacatalina <- select(islacatalina, 3:4)
colnames(islacatalina) <- c("Year", "Isla Catalina RLI")



ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("NOAA Coral Luminescence Data (RLI, 5-year Running Average)"),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  fluidRow(
  column(3, actionButton("laparguera", "La Parguera Data"),
  actionButton("mona", "Mona Island Data"),
  actionButton("isla", "Isla Catalina Data"))),
  fluidRow(
  column(3, offset = 5, actionButton("visualize", "Visualize Data"))),
  fluidRow(
  column(7, offset = 5, checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "Add to plot", 
  c("La Parguera" = "La Parguera", "Mona Island" = "Mona Island", "Isla Catalina" = "Isla Catalina"))),
  fluidRow(
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'), 
  plotOutput("plot1")
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 17.95, lng = - 67.05, popup = "La Parguera ") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.00, lng = -67.50, popup = "Mona Island") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.2, lng = -69.00, popup = "Isla Catalina")
  })
  observeEvent(input$laparguera, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(parguera, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$mona, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(monaisland, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$isla, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(islacatalina, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$visualize, {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot( 
  {
    if (input$checkbox == c("Mona Island"))
    {
    gplot <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
    geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot)
    }
    else if(input$checkbox == c("La Parguera", "Mona Island"))
    {
      gplot2 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
        geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
        ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
      print(gplot2)
    }
    else if (input$checkbox == c("La Parguera", "Mona Island", "Isla Catalina")) 
    {
      gplot3 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
        geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
        ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
      print(gplot3)
    }
    else if(input$checkbox == c("Mona Island", "Isla Catalina")) 
    {
      gplot4 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
        geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
        ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
      print(gplot4)
    }
  else if(input$checkbox == c("La Parguera", "Isla Catalina")) 
  {
    gplot5 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
      geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot5)
  }
  else if(input$checkbox == c("Isla Catalina")) 
  {
    gplot6 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
      geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot6)
  }
  else if(input$checkbox == c("La Parguera")) 
  {
    gplot7 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
      geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot7)
  }
  else if(is.null(input$checkbox)) 
  {
   print("Check some damn boxes")
  }

      })

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think the problem is, I don't really know what type of input I get from the checkbox. I assumed it was a character vector, but I'm not sure, and the documentation wasn't very helpful (at least for me).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I normally prefer to post some working code, but this time I couldn't because I do not have access to your data: my apologies.

Some consideration:

- In `checkboxGroupInput` you just need a plain character vector, i.e. you don't need to name columns etc.

  - The resulting `input$checkbox` is another character vector
  - `checkboxGroupInput` is designed to allow more than one input at a time, so the output can be a vector with more than one entry.
  - (minor) Rather than a cascade of `if` I normally prefer to use switch (**edited: but it works only for 1 element comparisons**), as it makes the code more readable (but it is personal taste).

In your case, to decrease the risk of errors (often due to a reactive calling the code more than once), in `output$plot1` you could use

```
cols <- isolate(input$checkbox)
```

Also, rather than the existing code for `output$plot1`, you could eliminate an `observeEvent` in this way:

```
# snippet - not tested
#
# observeEvent(input$visualize, {  # this is redundant
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot( 
      if(is.null(input$visualize)) return()  # this is all you need to make output$plot1 reactive to input$visualize
      cols <- isolate(input$checkbox)
      if (cols == c("Mona Island"))
        {
```

The proliferation of nested reactive elements is never a good thing in shiny (among other things it causes unnecessarily the code to run repeatedly, burning CPU cycles).

If useful, I recently posted on SO a code example with `checkboxGroupInput`. See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414932/r-shiny-observeevent-issues)

If you still get errors I would suggest to post the links to allow me or others to get your data and post back a working example.

**Working Example and "new comments"**

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

plotdata <- read.csv("RShinyCoral.csv")
colnames(plotdata) <- c("Year1", "RLIMona", "Year2", "RLICatalina", "Year3", "RLILaParguera1998", "Year4", "RLILAPARGUERA2004")
parguera <- read.csv("RShinyCoral.csv")
parguera <- select(parguera, 5:8)
colnames(parguera) <- c("Year", "1998 Expedition", "Year", "2004 Expedition")
monaisland <- read.csv("RShinyCoral.csv")
monaisland <- select(monaisland, 1:2)
colnames(monaisland) <- c("Year", "Mona Island RLI")
islacatalina <- read.csv("RShinyCoral.csv")
islacatalina <- select(islacatalina, 3:4)
colnames(islacatalina) <- c("Year", "Isla Catalina RLI")



ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("NOAA Coral Luminescence Data (RLI, 5-year Running Average)"),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, actionButton("laparguera", "La Parguera Data"),
           actionButton("mona", "Mona Island Data"),
           actionButton("isla", "Isla Catalina Data")),

    column(9, 
      actionButton("visualize", "Add to Plot"),

      checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", label = NULL, 
                                             c("La Parguera",  "Mona Island", "Isla Catalina"))
      )),
    fluidRow(column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')), 
     column(6,  plotOutput("plot1"))
     )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 17.95, lng = - 67.05, popup = "La Parguera ") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.00, lng = -67.50, popup = "Mona Island") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.2, lng = -69.00, popup = "Isla Catalina")
  })
  observeEvent(input$laparguera, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(parguera, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$mona, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(monaisland, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$isla, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(islacatalina, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    if(length(input$visualize) == 0 ) return()
    isolate({
      if(length(input$checkbox) == 0) return()
      incheckbox <- input$checkbox
    }) # end isolate
    if(length(incheckbox) == 1) {
    switch(incheckbox,
      "Mona Island"= { gplot <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                          geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                          ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                       print(gplot) },
      "Isla Catalina"= { gplot6 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                          geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                          ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                         print(gplot6) },
      "La Parguera"= { gplot7 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                          geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                          ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                       print(gplot7) }
                       ) # end switch
    } else if(length(incheckbox) == 2) {
             if(all(c("La Parguera", "Mona Island") %in% incheckbox)) {
                gplot2 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                  geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                  ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                print(gplot2)
          }  else if( all(c("Mona Island", "Isla Catalina") %in% incheckbox))  {
                  gplot4 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                    geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                    ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                  print(gplot4)
          } else if(all(c("La Parguera", "Isla Catalina") %in% incheckbox))    {
                  gplot5 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                    geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                    ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                  print(gplot5)  
                }
         }  else if ( all(c("La Parguera", "Mona Island", "Isla Catalina") %in% incheckbox)) {
                  gplot3 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
                    geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
                    ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
                  print(gplot3)
          } 

    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code above works for me :)

Apart the UI changes (made to get a bit tidier UI and see what was happening), the key is the `if` cascade`.
Take into account:

- `if` only works for one element.  If you compare a vector of length >1 with another vector >1, only the first matching element of the first vector is considered.
- I do not consider my code particular elegant (I do not exclude later to get some better ideas!), but it should work (please let me know if it doesn't).
- Suppose you have selected 3 elements. `all(c("La Parguera", "Mona Island") %in% incheckbox)` would always be true. This  is why currently I split the comparisons by number of elements (but there are probably other alternatives using other `set` operators like `setdiff`).

  Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am still unable to get the code to work, unfortunately. I am trying to figure out how to send you my data. @Enzo

Comment: Can you get the data? If not, I'm not super sure how to share a CSV file on here.

Comment: @ Enzo        
            https://www.dropbox.com/s/50emrio782fosiy/RShinyCoral.csv?dl=0

Comment: @madhatter5  I managed to download and I've uploaded above some working code.  Please note you'll find it in my earlier response  **below** my previous comments. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much Enzo! I will let you know soonish. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If appropriate, accept my post as a solution for your query.  Thanks!