# checkBoxGroupInput and if statements (data included)

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I posted a similar question before ([Errors in if statements in R Shiny checkBoxGroupInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419173/errors-in-if-statements-in-r-shiny-checkboxgroupinput/43419728#43419728))

but as someone pointed out I had not included relevant data. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

plotdata <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
colnames(plotdata) <- c("Year1", "RLIMona", "Year2", "RLICatalina", "Year3", "RLILaParguera1998", "Year4", "RLILAPARGUERA2004")
parguera <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
parguera <- select(parguera, 5:8)
colnames(parguera) <- c("Year", "1998 Expedition", "Year", "2004 Expedition")
monaisland <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
monaisland <- select(monaisland, 1:2)
colnames(monaisland) <- c("Year", "Mona Island RLI")
islacatalina <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch/RShinyCoral.csv")
islacatalina <- select(islacatalina, 3:4)
colnames(islacatalina) <- c("Year", "Isla Catalina RLI")



ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("NOAA Coral Luminescence Data (RLI, 5-year Running Average)"),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  fluidRow(
  column(3, actionButton("laparguera", "La Parguera Data"),
  actionButton("mona", "Mona Island Data"),
  actionButton("isla", "Isla Catalina Data"))),
  fluidRow(
  column(3, offset = 5, actionButton("visualize", "Visualize Data"))),
  fluidRow(
  column(7, offset = 5, checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "Add to plot", 
  c("La Parguera" = "La Parguera", "Mona Island" = "Mona Island", "Isla Catalina" = "Isla Catalina"))),
  fluidRow(
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'), 
  plotOutput("plot1")
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 17.95, lng = - 67.05, popup = "La Parguera ") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.00, lng = -67.50, popup = "Mona Island") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.2, lng = -69.00, popup = "Isla Catalina")
  })
  observeEvent(input$laparguera, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(parguera, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$mona, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(monaisland, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$isla, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(islacatalina, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$visualize, {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot( 
  {
    if (input$checkbox == c("Mona Island"))
    {
    gplot <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
    geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot)
    }
    else if(input$checkbox == c("La Parguera", "Mona Island"))
    {
      gplot2 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
        geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
        ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
      print(gplot2)
    }
    else if (input$checkbox == c("La Parguera", "Mona Island", "Isla Catalina")) 
    {
      gplot3 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
        geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
        ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
      print(gplot3)
    }
    else if(input$checkbox == c("Mona Island", "Isla Catalina")) 
    {
      gplot4 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
        geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
        ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
      print(gplot4)
    }
  else if(input$checkbox == c("La Parguera", "Isla Catalina")) 
  {
    gplot5 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
      geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot5)
  }
  else if(input$checkbox == c("Isla Catalina")) 
  {
    gplot6 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
      geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot6)
  }
  else if(input$checkbox == c("La Parguera")) 
  {
    gplot7 <- ggplot(data = plotdata) +
      geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = Year1, y = RLIMona), na.rm = TRUE) +
      ylab("Candelas (5-year Running Average)" )
    print(gplot7)
  }
  else if(is.null(input$checkbox)) 
  {
   print("Check some damn boxes")
  }

      })

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is my data:  filedropper.com/rshinycoral

I am having a problem using if statements to determine which plot will appear in the output, depending on which boxes are checked off. Please ignore for now the fact that my plots are the same, I'll change this later.

I am aware using if statements is not optimal, but I am having trouble using Enzo's suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post an actual link to your data. `filedropper.com/rshinycoral` does not link to anything.

Comment: Oh... how can I share a CSV file?

Comment: Go ahead and use filedropper, or anything else (dropbox is quite popular). Just figure out how to post a link using that service.

Comment: @ Mike Wise https://www.dropbox.com/s/50emrio782fosiy/RShinyCoral.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

The return value from input$checkbox is a character vector. I think your issue has nothing to do with shiny and checkboxes, rather `if` statements and vectors.

When R evaluates your predicate in an if statement, it only uses the first item in the vector (this is different behaviour to `ifelse`). so for example, try running the following code and observe both the result and the warning message:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")

if (a == c("a", "d")) {
   TRUE
} else {
  FALSE
}
```

So to fix your app, you will need to think about how you look for matching vectors. One way is to use `all` with `%in%` e.g:

```
if (all(c("a", "d") %in% a)) {
  TRUE
} else {
  FALSE 
}

if (all(c("a", "b") %in% a)) {
  TRUE
} else {
  FALSE
}
```