# ggplot and Shiny -- plots not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(anytime)

x<-read.csv("reddit_data_by_month.csv",header=T)
x["date"]<-anydate(x$month)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  title ="Reddit Data By Month",

  plotOutput("graph"),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(    
    column(6, 
      dateRangeInput("dates", label = h2("Date Range"), start = x$date[1], end = x$date[142], min = x$date[1], max = x$date[142], format = "mm/yyyy", startview = "year")

    ),
    column(6,
      checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h2("Data Sets"), 
                         choices = list("Accounts Created" = 1, "Comments" = 2, "Submissions" = 3, "Votes" = 4),
                         selected = NULL)
                                   #NULL
    )
  )
)
)
```

And the following server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)

x<-read.csv("reddit_data_by_month.csv",header=T)
x["date"]<-anydate(x$month)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  subsetData <- reactive({
    newData <- subset(x, date > as.Date(input$dates[1]) & as.Date(date) < as.Date(input$dates[2]))
    return(newData)
  })


  output$graph <- renderPlot({

    reactive({
    graph <- ggplot()

    if (grepl("1",input$checkGroup)){
      graph+geom_line(data=subsetData(),aes(x=date,y=accounts_created,color="red"))
    }      
    })

  })

})
```

My data is

```
structure(list(month = structure(1:142, .Label = c("2005-06", 
"2005-07", "2005-08", "2005-09", "2005-10", "2005-11", "2005-12", 
"2006-01", "2006-02", "2006-03", "2006-04", "2006-05", "2006-06", 
"2006-07", "2006-08", "2006-09", "2006-10", "2006-11", "2006-12", 
"2007-01", "2007-02", "2007-03", "2007-04", "2007-05", "2007-06", 
"2007-07", "2007-08", "2007-09", "2007-10", "2007-11", "2007-12", 
"2008-01", "2008-02", "2008-03", "2008-04", "2008-05", "2008-06", 
"2008-07", "2008-08", "2008-09", "2008-10", "2008-11", "2008-12", 
"2009-01", "2009-02", "2009-03", "2009-04", "2009-05", "2009-06", 
"2009-07", "2009-08", "2009-09", "2009-10", "2009-11", "2009-12", 
"2010-01", "2010-02", "2010-03", "2010-04", "2010-05", "2010-06", 
"2010-07", "2010-08", "2010-09", "2010-10", "2010-11", "2010-12", 
"2011-01", "2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", "2011-05", "2011-06", 
"2011-07", "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", "2011-11", "2011-12", 
"2012-01", "2012-02", "2012-03", "2012-04", "2012-05", "2012-06", 
"2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-12", 
"2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", 
"2013-07", "2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12", 
"2014-01", "2014-02", "2014-03", "2014-04", "2014-05", "2014-06", 
"2014-07", "2014-08", "2014-09", "2014-10", "2014-11", "2014-12", 
"2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", "2015-05", "2015-06", 
"2015-07", "2015-08", "2015-09", "2015-10", "2015-11", "2015-12", 
"2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", 
"2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", 
"2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03"), class = "factor"), accounts_created = c(48L, 
218L, 661L, 523L, 587L, 1385L, 3175L, 3694L, 4828L, 6907L, 6100L, 
7331L, 9847L, 9182L, 13517L, 14172L, 15607L, 20457L, 13691L, 
35775L, 23302L, 25936L, 29160L, 44229L, 28057L, 31420L, 35582L, 
35225L, 62448L, 28496L, 27419L, 33332L, 30771L, 33643L, 31474L, 
37465L, 40301L, 41403L, 38573L, 43099L, 44447L, 42032L, 43404L, 
52888L, 51064L, 58812L, 57449L, 54475L, 56395L, 64072L, 69943L, 
73429L, 79232L, 78275L, 87945L, 96497L, 92172L, 100400L, 99713L, 
99793L, 103067L, 115865L, 133784L, 152043L, 147386L, 156233L, 
170626L, 192205L, 194640L, 230680L, 219910L, 237391L, 233268L, 
243923L, 283644L, 322543L, 327499L, 325497L, 348052L, 425189L, 
419233L, 446002L, 468498L, 437879L, 543711L, 560730L, 574559L, 
523669L, 497116L, 490460L, 503286L, 628410L, 567514L, 623222L, 
632132L, 609353L, 566556L, 613224L, 639265L, 630462L, 650250L, 
696966L, 758969L, 799461L, 719222L, 735193L, 740941L, 703823L, 
683390L, 781972L, 807650L, 838559L, 829927L, 961855L, 1204939L, 
1082964L, 1098516L, 1494934L, 1009347L, 1020310L, 1048679L, 1294614L, 
1343828L, 1387719L, 1314019L, 1585696L, 1351193L, 1556725L, 2798107L, 
1376827L, 1343441L, 1290658L, 1328986L, 1429274L, 1803343L, 1204529L, 
1201884L, 1192114L, 1366015L, 1568402L, 1429326L, 1254460L), 
    comments = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2357L, 7953L, 9541L, 
    14321L, 19866L, 27423L, 29983L, 37587L, 50659L, 50773L, 54536L, 
    62362L, 60820L, 82659L, 97745L, 113684L, 127091L, 170643L, 
    180439L, 207659L, 225203L, 260123L, 274924L, 373975L, 362979L, 
    455129L, 441245L, 464387L, 468865L, 537406L, 579049L, 593005L, 
    597998L, 683651L, 789113L, 797219L, 852556L, 1058022L, 948344L, 
    1055005L, 1099697L, 1206715L, 1264047L, 1477059L, 1760218L, 
    2040509L, 2240352L, 2226624L, 2557647L, 2905450L, 2686848L, 
    3243501L, 3211545L, 3283363L, 3548140L, 4060855L, 4281423L, 
    4718729L, 5049686L, 5735450L, 5957395L, 6668561L, 6388389L, 
    7571304L, 7601725L, 8896402L, 9814580L, 10633712L, 12423445L, 
    12222905L, 13577570L, 13753896L, 14542605L, 16527084L, 16422774L, 
    17954424L, 19216041L, 20510389L, 21949445L, 24387949L, 25817623L, 
    23609848L, 24936572L, 24834710L, 26230630L, 30694351L, 27416555L, 
    30977337L, 33551836L, 33281887L, 33022329L, 35257639L, 35009325L, 
    32325018L, 36210545L, 37827440L, 40045414L, 43017721L, 39198081L, 
    42942717L, 42884781L, 42886243L, 42508122L, 47416897L, 47541298L, 
    45680630L, 47949180L, 46891046L, 49234627L, 54590153L, 48901554L, 
    55307000L, 55748704L, 55148495L, 55142182L, 59234553L, 58899315L, 
    56227874L, 60400360L, 58276635L, 59156435L, 62749684L, 59854458L, 
    64461004L, 64968014L, 65928553L, 66531676L, 67606088L, 70203145L, 
    67565561L, 72550880L, 71914026L, 73367953L, 79851397L, 72457238L, 
    74989033L), submissions = c(113L, 1075L, 2088L, 2439L, 3508L, 
    3714L, 5330L, 8128L, 9627L, 12683L, 12783L, 14941L, 17079L, 
    24899L, 42277L, 55163L, 38748L, 37220L, 36360L, 44261L, 47415L, 
    59045L, 62039L, 65580L, 62900L, 73995L, 84961L, 91521L, 101662L, 
    107142L, 110957L, 143287L, 147732L, 169897L, 168891L, 178929L, 
    192977L, 219036L, 213981L, 258796L, 284929L, 276948L, 287571L, 
    337394L, 334391L, 370394L, 367355L, 364984L, 392516L, 436016L, 
    445941L, 450769L, 468877L, 464344L, 498628L, 565217L, 518733L, 
    623178L, 634455L, 536295L, 499033L, 522386L, 561752L, 620834L, 
    653032L, 699986L, 750552L, 862205L, 837849L, 992189L, 984104L, 
    1101438L, 1172192L, 1281391L, 1474301L, 1503691L, 1627731L, 
    1666608L, 1796186L, 2028265L, 1996717L, 2188966L, 2315044L, 
    2336047L, 2430131L, 2727478L, 2822897L, 2645828L, 2848964L, 
    2769537L, 2802846L, 3224703L, 2969247L, 3286715L, 3458898L, 
    3334460L, 3290711L, 3470590L, 3404255L, 3342654L, 3657559L, 
    3617673L, 3897270L, 4311176L, 4258096L, 4457622L, 4256699L, 
    4327371L, 4248739L, 4654776L, 4760451L, 4736550L, 5021485L, 
    4977439L, 5156490L, 5705886L, 5298054L, 5851273L, 5819198L, 
    5979365L, 6061807L, 6143449L, 6390745L, 6524258L, 6690333L, 
    6578227L, 6762600L, 7814491L, 8011045L, 7427206L, 7358231L, 
    8018299L, 7952227L, 8157043L, 8430184L, 7943082L, 8657116L, 
    9036437L, 9275209L, 10079594L, 9141514L, 8320634L), votes_cast = c(1593, 
    7697, 21001, 25623, 38336, 53578, 140677, 251891, 281917, 
    354070, 412558, 527969, 508352, 670992, 916705, 872289, 969661, 
    1080387, 1000432, 1372822, 1418432, 1585620, 1870638, 2331648, 
    2298172, 2651797, 2712152, 3180503, 3140253, 3496048, 3966451, 
    4925835, 4929946, 4915463, 4153792, 4755783, 5567076, 6043979, 
    6311657, 7227888, 8008763, 7723053, 7969214, 9919486, 8544935, 
    9172783, 9684676, 10097245, 11040009, 12708002, 14921321, 
    15477325, 17129919, 16854507, 21118879, 22799456, 21307718, 
    23955640, 24015058, 24352578, 26711537, 29005400, 31540253, 
    36783663, 38717930, 42922895, 44721742, 51762788, 49547623, 
    60411718, 61635008, 76643286, 85136762, 91292574, 110235621, 
    111005564, 125330096, 131946776, 146746427, 170252197, 170174242, 
    192702118, 213439714, 227738040, 242492335, 270949434, 291082814, 
    276403018, 299625008, 303961085, 323300156, 367665686, 336187498, 
    386367195, 418442929, 417627992, 405759094, 420771491, 414721909, 
    389736074, 412008384, 422974888, 452019068, 477554760, 433357873, 
    476138296, 469425693, 469225454, 457406295, 489737473, 499537753, 
    481776130, 506470420, 507657165, 528570710, 572878135, 540936548, 
    613690994, 618378213, 622298648, 673896944.5, 716120978.6, 
    745813321.7, 788014837, 828691834, 842793081, 834890351, 
    914619383, 803209155, 825434703, 888020408, 936598904, 998290062, 
    863629375, 990641834, 842687530, 1118434460, 1243171165, 
    1266718016, 1362587431, 1296037003, 1290797207), date = structure(c(12935, 
    12965, 12996, 13027, 13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 
    13239, 13269, 13300, 13330, 13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 
    13514, 13545, 13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 
    13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 
    14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 
    14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 
    14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 
    14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 
    15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 
    15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 
    15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 
    15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 
    16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 
    16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 
    16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 
    17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 17226), class = "Date", tzone = "America/New_York")), row.names = c(NA, 
-142L), .Names = c("month", "accounts_created", "comments", "submissions", 
"votes_cast", "date"), class = "data.frame")
```

Obviously the server side is not fully fleshed out, but I cannot get the plot to appear when I check the first checkbox.  There are no errors in the console.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works.  I've just eliminated the redundant reactive within the `renderPlot` function (which in itself is an eager reactive, comparable to `observe`).
I am not terribly sure about using `grepl`, so in the context of this code I've just used `if`.

See my code in this answer for a complex set of components to address different behaviours with `checkboxGroupInput`: [checkBoxGroupInput and if statements (data included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430726/checkboxgroupinput-and-if-statements-data-included)

The example code is near the end of my comment.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)

x<-read.csv("accounts_created_by_month.csv",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
x["date"]<-anydate(x$month)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  title ="Reddit Data By Month",

  plotOutput("graph"),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(    
    column(6, 
           dateRangeInput("dates", label = h2("Date Range"), start = x$date[1], end = x$date[142], min = x$date[1], max = x$date[142], format = "mm/yyyy", startview = "year")

    ),
    column(6,
    checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h2("Data Sets"), 
                             choices = list("Accounts Created" = 1, "Comments" = 2, "Submissions" = 3, "Votes" = 4),
                             selected = NULL)
           #NULL
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output,session) {

subsetData <- reactive({
    newData <- subset(x, date > as.Date(input$dates[1]) & as.Date(date) < as.Date(input$dates[2]))
    return(newData)
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    if(length(input$checkGroup) == 0) return()
      graph <- ggplot()
      if (input$checkGroup == 1){
        graph+geom_line(data=subsetData(),aes(x=date,y=accounts_created,color="red"))
      }      
    })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: My remaining issue has to do with checking the remaining combinations of conditions.  The above code works if the first check box is selected.  My intent was to then carry on with else if statements for the remaining conditions.  However, if I try `else if(input$checkGroup==c(1,2)){` then I get a warning in the console that says *the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used* and none of the additional plots show up as the boxes are checked,,,

Comment: Figured it out....have to order my conditional checks by the number of choices...all the single checks first, followed by all the checks of length 2, then length 3...