# newby confusion with checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

if I have a checkboxGroup defined as

```
 checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h2("Data Sets"), 
                     choices = list("Accounts Created" = 1, "Comments" = 2,
                                    "Submissions" = 3, "Votes" = 4),
                     selected = NULL)
```

Then on the server side, how do I access the selection status of the four boxes?  Is it `input$checkGroup[1]`, `input$checkGroup[2]`, etc with 0/1 values?  Or is `input$checkGroup` variable length containing only the values selected?  Very confused as to how to determine if, for example, the first and third boxes are checked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `checkboxGroupInput` is a vector.

It is intended to be used when you may want to select more than one element at the same time.

To avoid confusion (and avoid letting our reactive have a run every time you select a box) it works best in conjunction with an action button:

1. once you have done your selection (one or many more items);
2. you can push the action button for execution. This makes sure that you process the user's selection only when the user is ready for it.

Also, sometime I prefer not to use a list, but  just a simple vector, e.g.:

```
checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h2("Data Sets"), 
                     choices = c("Accounts Created", "Comments",
                                    "Submissions", "Votes"),
                     selected = NULL)
```

Then you can process on the server side the character vector, that will have the different value, e.g.  `input$checkGroup` may be equal to `c("Accounts Created", "Comments")` if the first two boxes have been selected, and so on.

Perhaps the code I posted in reply to the following SO question may be of help [R Shiny observeEvent issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414932/r-shiny-observeevent-issues/43416444#43416444)

Please take into consideration that if many elements will be selected, you need to have a proper treatment pipeline.  For example, `if` (or `switch`) only works for one elements at the time, and if you want to scan the output vector one element at the time, it works greatly.  If you r treatment is more complex you need to think it through carefully.

Please do not hesitate to ask for more if it is not clear.

Comment: That makes sense, though I'm still running into issues implementing.  I think my question now is beyond the OP, so I've posted a new one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461690/ggplot-and-shiny-plots-not-appearing)

Answer (score 1):

They are treated as a character vector whose length is equal to the number of checked boxes. Here's a very simple shiny app showing you how `checkboxGroup`s are treated:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h2("Data Sets"), 
                     choices = list("Accounts Created" = 1, "Comments" = 2,
                                    "Submissions" = 3, "Votes" = 4),
                     selected = NULL),
  verbatimTextOutput("checkBoxText")
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
 output$checkBoxText <- renderText({input$checkGroup})
}

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T) )
```

Notice how in the app the values are what are stored (not the labels). So if you select `"Accounts Created"`, `input$checkGroup` will contain `1` and not `"Accounts Created"`